# Android how can I make text with stroke

Tags: android, android-view

I am having few buttons added programatically and I want to set their text to be with black border and white inside, stroke, outline, or whatever it is called...
How can I do that? I think I need some style.xml but I can't find any.
I want the text to be just like this, simple
http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/855_cssProperties/images/textStroke.jpg

Answer (score -1):

**1.** create three .xml in `res/drawable`:

**button_normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners android:radius="3dip" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

**button_focused.xml**

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners android:radius="3dip" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

**button_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal.xml" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
```

**2.** set background with `button_background.xml` in your `layout.xml` or code

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.button_background.xml));
```

more information:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape